# Group-by for function that generates more than one variable

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, ta-lib

I am trying to calculate some group-by items using Technical analysis library (TA-lib) here:
https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/

Some of the functions such as AROON will generate two variables, AR_UP and AR_DOWN.

Without doing group-by, I would use the following:

```
dft['AR_UP'], dft['AR_DOWN'] = ta.AROON(dft['High'], dft['Low'], 14)
```

And it would generate AR_UP and AR_DOWN in dft

However, when I try to apply a group-by:

```
grouped=dft.groupby(["StockCode"]).apply(lambda x: (ta.AROON(x['High'], x['Low'], 14)))
```

This gives me grouped as:

```
StockCode
ABA    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
ABP    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
ABW    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
ACQ    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
ACU    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
                             ...                        
WTL    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
WZR    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
XPL    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
YBR    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
Z1P    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
Length: 282, dtype: object
```

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

I would also like to reassign this back to the original dataframe, so something like:

```
grouped=(grouped.reset_index()
.groupby("StockCode",as_index=False)
.apply(lambda x: x.assign (AR_UP, AR_DOWN=(ta.AROON(x['High'], x['Low'], 14))))
.set_index('index') )
```

Would it be possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? It works for my example function but I couldn't install the package. Maybe it will work for your function too. `groupby` followed by `apply` doesn't work well with multiple return values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dft={'High': range(11,21),
     'Low': range(1,11),
     'StockCode':np.append(np.repeat("A", 6), np.repeat("B", 4))}

dft=pd.DataFrame(dft)

dft=dft.sort_values("StockCode")

def aroon(x, y, n):
    return x/sum(x)*n, y/sum(y)*n

def my(x):
    a, b=aroon(x["High"], x["Low"], 2)
    return pd.DataFrame({"UP":a, "LOW":b})

grp=dft.groupby("StockCode").apply(lambda x: my(x))

dat=pd.concat([dft, grp], axis=1)

print dat

   High  Low StockCode       LOW        UP
0    11    1         A  0.095238  0.271605
1    12    2         A  0.190476  0.296296
2    13    3         A  0.285714  0.320988
3    14    4         A  0.380952  0.345679
4    15    5         A  0.476190  0.370370
5    16    6         A  0.571429  0.395062
6    17    7         B  0.411765  0.459459
7    18    8         B  0.470588  0.486486
8    19    9         B  0.529412  0.513514
9    20   10         B  0.588235  0.540541
```